# XPath evaluation on document created dynamically not working

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

**Updated/Simplified based on Mathias's comment:**

I'm trying to dynamically create an HTML Document and then find elements within the DOM via XPath.

What's odd is that the created Document looks to be properly constructed and querying it with `document.querySelector('<some el>')` for example works as expected.

However, `document.evaluate` is always returning null for every XPath.

**Update #2:** This is true for Chrome + Safari. Everything works as expected in Firefox.

```
function createDocumentFromHTMLContent(htmlContent) {
  const htmlEl = document.createElement('HTML');
  htmlEl.innerHTML = htmlContent;

  const doctype = document.implementation.createDocumentType('html', '', '');
  const doc = document.implementation.createDocument('', 'html', doctype);
  doc.replaceChild(htmlEl, doc.firstElementChild);
  return doc;
}

function getElementByXpath(path, doc) {
  doc = doc || document;
  return doc.evaluate(path, doc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

const pageContent = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Yup</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</body>
</html>
`;

const doc = createDocumentFromHTMLContent(pageContent);
const xpath = '/html[1]/body[1]/h1';
const onDoc = {
  viaXPath: getElementByXpath(xpath, doc),
  viaSelector: doc.querySelector('h1'),
};

const onDocument = {
  viaXPath: getElementByXpath(xpath, document),
  viaSelector: document.querySelector('h1'),
};

const summarize = (obj) => `XPath El: ${!!obj.viaXPath}, Selector El: ${!!obj.viaSelector}`;

const summaryEl = document.createElement('p');
summaryEl.innerHTML = `Via Document: ${summarize(onDocument)}<br />Via Doc: ${summarize(onDoc)}`;
document.body.appendChild(summaryEl);
```

Here's the above in a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/two2hg0z/

I can't figure out why XPath selection works on one document object, but not the other.

Any help is appreciated! Very stumped.

Comment: Please include all relevant code here, instead of only linking to a fiddle. Also, please say what "isn't working as expected" means. If you suspect that the problem has to do with XPath, it would also make sense to directly show the HTML document that is fetched in your code. Thanks!

Comment: Great feedback, Mathias. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I still do not understand what you mean by "XPath selection works on one document object, but not the other". If I open the jsfiddle, I see `Via Document: XPath El: true, Selector El: true` and `Via Doc: XPath El: true, Selector El: true`. Can you please explain what you expected the output to be vs. the actual output?

Comment: I imagine you're using Firefox, am I right? On Google Chrome and Safari, it ouputs false on the second line. https://imgur.com/a/wiPXcXH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what happens here in webkit browsers, probably they don't like to `Document.replaceChild` the `documentElement`, or maybe it's because you are setting some markup that is actually invalid inside an `<html>` element (for instance the Doctype should actually be set outside, it can't contain an <html> node etc. but anyway, **the correct way to parse a string as a Document is through the use of a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)**:

```js
function createDocumentFromHTMLContent(htmlContent) {
  return new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlContent, 'text/html');
}

function getElementByXpath(path, doc) {
  doc = doc || document;
  return doc.evaluate(path, doc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

const pageContent = `
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Yup</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</body>
</html>
`;
const doc = createDocumentFromHTMLContent(pageContent);

const xpath = '/html[1]/body[1]/h1';
const onDoc = {
  viaXPath: getElementByXpath(xpath, doc),
  viaSelector: doc.querySelector('h1'),
};

const onDocument = {
  viaXPath: getElementByXpath(xpath, document),
  viaSelector: document.querySelector('h1'),
};

const summarize = (obj) => `XPath El: ${!!obj.viaXPath}, Selector El: ${!!obj.viaSelector}`;

const summaryEl = document.createElement('p');
summaryEl.innerHTML = `Via Document: ${summarize(onDocument)}<br />Via Doc: ${summarize(onDoc)}`;
document.body.appendChild(summaryEl);
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
```

Note that if instead of replacing the `documentElement`, you did [set its innerHTML to the one of your generated HTMLElement](https://jsfiddle.net/r30was2z/), it would also have worked in Chrome, but not in Firefox anymore ;-)